# Can I disable the wall jump?

Tags: wunderling-dx

At the start of world 4 you unlock a wall jump. I've found the wall jump trivializes getting some of the collectibles in the first 3 worlds. I've been trying not to use it, but I keep activating it on accident. Is there a way to disable the wall jump ability?